# ng-grid only the first 6 rows displayed in MAC OS

Tags: ng-grid

I am a beginner in java web apps and Javascripts. I tried the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275857/turnoff-scrolling-within-angular-ui-ng-grid).

The solution does not work under MAC OS. I only see the 6 rows of data. The grid does not get adjusted to the number of rows returned by the JSON query. The calculated height of the grid in my code is correct and should be able to fit all rows of data. I tried the online sample code given that uses `ngGridFlexibleHeightPlugin` and I see one row when I use

```
< div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions" ng-style="getHeight()"></div>
```

(intentional space after "< div" for this post) .

I am using Angular 1.3.x, Apache Tomcat 8.0.17 and MAC OS 10.10. Any ideas, would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar problem. If ng-grid had more than 50 rows, then it was displaying only 6 rows. If I reduced the number of rows to 50 or less by deleting data in JSON file, it was working.

I found `virtualizationThreshold: 50` in the [ng-grid configuration options wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options). Overriding the default value of `virtualizationThreshold` to a greater value seemed logical to me (I'm also newbie), So, I set it to 100 (i.e., `virtualizationThreshold: 100`), and it started displaying all the rows (which was around 60) - [my sample here](http://rawgit.com/abhijithda/jaina/master/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS file changes helped solve this issue.

```
/*style.css*/


.gridStyle {
border: 1px solid rgb(212,212,212);
height: auto !important;
width: 100%;
min-height: 600px !important;
}

.ngViewport{
height: auto !important;
width: 400px;
min-height: 600px !important;
}

.ng-scope {
height: auto !important;
}

.ngCell  {
  display : table-cell;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow:visible;
  position: static;
}

.ngRow {
  display : table-row;
  height: auto !important;
  position: static;
}

.ngCellText{
  height: auto !important;
  white-space: normal;
  overflow:visible;
}
```